# Using PopStateEvent correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webapi

I have the following code implemented, where when users press the back/forward button of the browser, it will trigger the PopStateEvent to do an exit confirmation, where if the users confirm their exit, exitToServer() function will be called. exitToServer() function contains HTTP request to server to inform them that this particular userID is going to exit.

```
// implementation of PopStateEvent
useEffect(() =\> {
        console.log("Popstateevent useeffect called");

        const handlePopState = (event: PopStateEvent) => {
            console.log("Popstateevent occurred");
            
            const exitConfirmation = window.confirm('Leaving so soon? Chat will be lost.');
            if (exitConfirmation) {
                exitToServer();
            } else {
                // Prevent leaving the page
                event.preventDefault();
                // Restore the URL to the current one
                window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href);
            }
        };
    
        window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
        console.log("Attached event")
    
        return () => {
            console.log("popstate event cleanup called")
            window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
        };
    }, []);
```

```
// exit to server function that works with BeforeUnloadEvent
const exitToServer = async () =\> {

        const dataToSend = {
        username: usernameToSend
        };
    
        console.log("sending exit to server")
    
        try {
            await fetch(`http://${host}:${port}/exit`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(
                dataToSend)
            });
    
            console.log(dataToSend);
    
            const exitConfirmation = 'Leaving so soon?';
            return exitConfirmation;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending message:', error);
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Here is my implementation of the BeforeUnloadEvent that is implemented on top of the PopStateEvent: (It only works for refresh and close tab button)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleBeforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {

            exitToServer();

            const exitConfirmation = 'Leaving so soon? Chat will be lost.';
            event.returnValue = exitConfirmation;
            return exitConfirmation;
        };

        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
        };
    }, []);
```

The UseEffect() does not work as when I tried logging to the inspector, I realize that the PopStateEvent was never triggered when i activate the browser's back button. Is there any way to go about this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I had a very similar problem with `popstate` this week using React/TypeScript/React Router v6. I ended up using `window.onbeforeunload = function() => { return "can't override this message" }` instead. This uses the browser's default form changed dialog, which unfortunately can't be customised. Other thing worth mentioning is `onbeforeunload` isn't just the browser back button, it's refresh, forward and close tab too.

Comment: I did implement BeforeUnloadEvent() on top of this PopStateEvent(). Reason being - the BeforeUnloadEvent worked for refresh and browser close button but not the back and forward buttons. I'll attach the code in the next comment.

Comment: sorry, it's hard to see the code in that format. i'll include it in the post.

Comment: `onbeforeunload` doesn't work for android chrome browser back button, that's worth mentoning too. It's a joke. Apparently it's a wider UX problem blocking browser functionality and I've seen recommendations to save form state in session storage and reloading the form instead of blocking browser functionality. I'm not convinced.

Comment: I've tried it on edge browser too, it doesn't work... wonder if it's an issue with the code

Comment: `onbeforeunload` does work for android chrome browser back button. I was wrong.